# "Unknown Error" in Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#/) on the *Microsoft Planner* (formerly *Tasks*) API.

I can requests users fine, e.g. `/beta/users`.

But when I try to access my plans using `/beta/me/plans` or `/beta/plans/{ID}`, I get an unknown error with the details below:

`Status Code: 403`

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "62299f57-1792-4b0c-8b60-8613c54f4f50",
            "date": "2017-01-17T21:12:51"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query the tasks on a plan that I own.

Comment: I can't get this issue to repro. In Graph Explorer, if you sign out and use the default demo tenant and issue the call to graph.microsoft.com/beta/plans, does it return with a 200?

Comment: With the demo tenant, I get
    `{
        "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#plans",
        "value": []
    }`

When logged in, I get the "Unknown Error" above.

Comment: For new visitors to this page: Status Code: 403 gives some clues to the issue, beyond the highly unhelpful "UnknownError" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0):

This API has changed. This URL should be

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/plans`