# UnknownError when retrieving a Plan via Groups or Planner API methods

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting the same error as ["Unknown Error" in Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707173/unknown-error-in-microsoft-graph-explorer), hitting the v1 and the beta api directly. E.g. `beta/groups/<group id>/planner/plans` or, `beta/planner/plans/<plan id>`

It shows as a `401`, but error code is `UnknownError`. I know the plan exists because I can visit it in the browser. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Full output:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "**UnknownError**",
        "message": "...401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials....
                    You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the 
                    credentials that you supplied...",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "02fde3c3-a56c-4134-b483-0b53aee88410",
            "date": "2017-09-13T05:51:31"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) What OAUTH flow are you using (`authoriztion_code`,`implicit`,`client_credentials`, etc), 2) Which scopes did you request, and 3) Have you gone through the Admin Consent process yet?

Comment: I'm trying to use client credentials, and I can add a Group and retrieve all groups (v1.0/groups). Only Planner requests that are giving me trouble. Everything works fine if I connect interactively (I think that's 'authorization code' in this case) but not with client credentials. I'm using Group.ReadWrite.All as well as others in both cases (in the 'auth code' case I request it directly, in the client cred case I've set it in the app reg portal and yes, I've gone through the Admin Consent process (recall I can add and read groups just not plans). By the way, I'm using PowerShell here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid Application permissions (which are used the `client_credentials` flow) are not supported with Planner. In order to interact with Plans, you'll need to use a flow that supports Delegated permissions.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplan_get.md):

> - Delegated (work or school account): `Group.Read.All`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`
> - Delegated (personal Microsoft account): Not supported
> - **Application: Not supported**

Comment: Ah, missed that, thanks Marc. It's quite a pity for a background service app. Do you know if this is coming at some point or shall I just check UserVoice (e.g. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5904632-task-management-api)

Comment: I would check UserVoice. I know these scopes are regularly looked at but there is some justifiable hesitation when it comes expanding application scopes.

Comment: Found an existing UserVoice for this for anyone who wants to up-vote it: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17719684-allow-access-to-planner-using-client-credentials-f